# "Camels" means "Cigars with the brand (Camel)"?

Tags: word-meaning, singular-vs-plural, countability

In a story I ran into these:

> Mr. Martin bought the pack of Camels.

and

> He transferred the Camels from his overcoat to a jacket pocket.

and

> Mrs. Barrows smoked only Luckies.

I think the brands of the cigars are *Camel* and *Lucky*. Then what is that S at the their ends for?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in this case these are brand names. You can tell by the context and the fact that "Lucky" and "Camel" are capitalized, indicating that these are proper nouns. The "s" at the end of the Mr. Martin sentence indicates plurality; he bought one pack of cigarettes, but since there is more than one cigarette in the pack, it is plural. As for the Mrs. Barrows sentence, I googled it and the cigarette name is "Lucky Strike" but a nickname for them is "Luckies" so in this case the "s" at the end doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: The 's' at the end of Luckies means exactly the same thing as the 's' at the end of Camels: plurality. "Mrs. Barrows smoked only Luckies" is exactly the same construction as "Mrs. Barrows ate only yellow apples."